# FAB not triggering inside of AlertDialog android kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

I have a LinearLayout with 7 FAB's inside, and I'm trying to change their background tint color by clicking, the thing is, the first FAB does trigger and change the color but the rest doesn't and also, if I click in the first FAB and  then in the rest of them, they change the tint color, but doesn't trigger! I tried to debug but nothig..

This is what I did.

```
val monday: FloatingActionButton = dialogLayout.findViewById(R.id.monday);
val tuesday: FloatingActionButton = dialogLayout.findViewById(R.id.tuesday);

 monday.setOnClickListener {
     if(java.lang.String.format("#%06X", 0xFFFFFF and monday.backgroundTintList?.defaultColor!!) == "#C9C9C9"){
         monday.backgroundTintList = ColorStateList.valueOf(resources.getColor(R.color.accent));
      }
      else{
          monday.backgroundTintList = ColorStateList.valueOf(Color.parseColor("#c9c9c9"));
      }
        }
        tuesday.setOnClickListener {
            if(java.lang.String.format("#%06X", 0xFFFFFF and monday.backgroundTintList?.defaultColor!!) == "#C9C9C9"){
                tuesday.backgroundTintList = ColorStateList.valueOf(resources.getColor(R.color.accent));
            }
            else{
                tuesday.backgroundTintList = ColorStateList.valueOf(Color.parseColor("#c9c9c9"));
            }
        }
```

It's very weird, but I think it has to do with the view it self as if the first item registered surpass the other ones.. I don't know!

Comment: Nathiel :: Could you please post your xml also?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is your problem:

```
 tuesday.setOnClickListener {
            if(java.lang.String.format("#%06X", 0xFFFFFF and ----------> monday.backgroundTintList?.defaultColor!!) == "#C9C9C9"){ <----------------------
                tuesday.backgroundTintList = ColorStateList.valueOf(resources.getColor(R.color.accent));
            }
            else{
                tuesday.backgroundTintList = ColorStateList.valueOf(Color.parseColor("#c9c9c9"));
            }
        }
```

**You are comparing to Monday's state and not Tuesday's. I am guessing this happens in the rest of your buttons.**